# CMS Made Simple - Changing Header Based on Variable

Tags: templates, cookies, session-variables, cmsmadesimple

I have been asked to add some code for a CMS Made Simple site. The site has a landing page as well as the main homepage. I want to change the logo in the header (it is set my the css) for all pages for a visitor's session depending on whether the visitor came to the landing page first or the homepage first.

So if a visitor comes to the landing page and then goes to other pages in the site, those other pages should all use the landing page logo, but if the visitor does not go to that landing page first, then the other site pages should use the default logo.

I am not familiar with CMS Made Simple so I'm not sure how to go about this. I was thinking to set a session variable, or create a cookie, and then based on that value add some code to the templates (the landing page template and default template).

The current code in the header for the landing page is:

```
<div id="logo"><h1>{cms_selflink dir="start" text="call and data roaming experts" class="logoAero"}</h1></div>
```

And the css is:

```
h1 a.logoAero {
  display: block;
  width: 310px;
  height: 82px;
  background: url(/images/web/logoAero.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Any guidance on how to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you should build an UDT (User Defined Tags).

To do that, go in the admin under Extensions > User Defined Tags.

Create a tag (for instance, "origin") with the following code:

```
if(isset($params['origin']))
{
  $_SESSION['website_origin'] = $params['origin'];
}

if(isset($_SESSION['website_origin']))
{
  $smarty->assign('website_origin', $_SESSION['website_origin']);
}
```

In the two "origin" pages, you can use the following code:

```
{origin origin="foo"}

{origin origin="bar"}
```

On the other pages, use the code

```
{origin}
```

In your template you can now test the existence of the variable `website_origin` and play with it:

```
{if isset($website_origin)}<h1>{$website_origin}</h1>{/if}
```